# cellForRowAtIndexPath returns nil on device

Tags: iphone, ios4, tableview

I spent few hours trying to resolve one very strange issue, but I really don't know how to proceed.

I have a grouped UITableView referenced from XIB populated with custom (subclassed) UITableViewCell cells. All the cells (two section with one cell each) are visible and I am trying to get one of them by calling:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
LocationSearchFilterCell *cell = (LocationSearchFilterCell *)[filterTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

On Simulator 4.2 the cell is returned properly;
On Device 4.0.x the code returns NIL;
On Simulator 4.0.x the code returns NIL;
On Simulator 4.1 the cell is returned properly **BUT NOT** on Device 4.1.

The strangest thing is that I am using this approach on few other places within the application and the cell is always returned properly. I guess it is some strange combination of me doing something differently combined with some iOS bug.

**Any idea ?**

P.S. In situation where NIL is returned, by using GDB I get the pointer of the cell when it is created and call:

```
(gdb) po (void *)[filterTable indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)0x7b08520]
```

and I get a valid index path (that matches the one I am providing) which means the cell is valid and present into the table view.
I have even tried passing the object returned by this last call (by pointer) and I still get NIL.

Comment: In what method are you trying to get the cell?

Comment: Custom method that gets called on a button press.

Comment: try to check if the returned object really is of type LocationSearchFilterCell: ( [cell isKindOfClass:[LocationSearchFilterCell class]] )

Comment: no the type was not the problem; see my answer below; anyway thanks for the comments that triggered proper reasoning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting,

It turned out someone is hiding the table view before I try to get the cell (`stupid me :)`).

What I was doing was, triggering an animation to hide the table view (nested into some methods I am calling from the method where I try to get the cell). Because I was stopped on a breakpoint the animation was also stopped, so it seamed to me like the table view is visible.

What I don't understand still is why the table view is threaded as hidden although the animation is still not finished (and I only change the frame in the animation and set the table hidden after the animation is finished) ?

I guess the answer to this question is the key point why on different combinations of Device / Simulator / iOS I get different behavior. Anyway the solution is as simple as moving the two lines I've posted above at the top of the method.

**Thanks to Rits for his question that triggered my reasoning ;)**

regards